# Is there a difference in the thematic roles of the italicized constituents of these two sentences?

Tags: thematic-roles

i. Justin knitted *Mary* some outfits.

ii. Justin knitted some outfits *for Mary*.

Is there a difference in the thematic roles of the italicized constituents of these two sentences?

They both look like beneficiaries to me. However, I'm not sure whether they're the same.

Comment: This is a case of the benefactive mimicking the role of dative receiver and undergoing dative alternation. This can happen to a benefactive phrase with _for_, **provided** the benefactee receives the direct object as a result of the action of the verb. Exx: _He fixed supper for her ==> He fixed her supper_ , but _He fixed the car for her ==> *He fixed her the car_ does not work. So it's a beneficiary pretending to be a dative, and getting close enough to work under the right circumstances.